# JQuery list drop down menu issue

Tags: javascript, fonts, drop-down-menu

Yes, it is one of those questions, and I have seen the other similar questions on SO, but could not solve my issue with all available recommendations. I am new to Javascript.

I have created a small list of fonts I can click on to dynamically change the font on my page. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='L3_RIGHT'>
    <ul id="ffonts"><li>Font Selection:</li></ul>
</div>
```

In document-ready, I add `<li>` entries for each font. When I click on any font name, the page is updated successfully.

I would like to transform that list into a drop down list to take less space on the page. I thought the following would help:

```
$("#ffonts li").hover(
    function(){$(this).find("ul").slideDown(200);}, 
    function(){$(this).find("ul").slideUp(400);});
```

but it does not. It does not produce the drop-down effect (and yes it is called in document-ready after `<li>` entries are created). I tried variations of this and ideas suggested here and there on the net, but no success.

How should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you point to an example on the web of what you are trying to accomplish?  Usually a drop down list is a `select` with `option` tags.  But, that's not what you are doing here - I assume on purpose.

Comment: @evan Good point. I did not think about select... I'll try it...

Comment: @evan I finally solved my issue with a select. If you create a solution, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hover function uses the 'li' element as 'this' and 'find' only finds elements deeper in the dom. Since 'ul' is higher in the dom, you can do a $(this).parents('ul') (or '.parent()' if you know 'li' is the direct descendant in all cases) and then your slide function should be working on the correct element.

I expanded on your example a little bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/fEdpA/1/

You probably don't want 'Font Selection:' inside of your 'li' element because it will disappear when the ul slides up, that's where your fonts go. In my example I just create a label for you and get the parent, then you can look inside with 'find' and get the 'ul'.

Comment: The code you suggest indeed creates a drop down effect successfully, but when I move the mouse over a menu item, it closes before I can have a chance to select an item lol.

Comment: Haha sorry about that, If you just target the entire div and make the css have the div as display: inline-block, it will stay open while hovering over anything inside the div as well. I updated the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

Usually a drop down list is a `select` with `option` tags.  Glad my comment worked for you!

As a note for others that might see this question/answer it is generally better not to reinvent common inputs.  There are a lot of tools out there to help people that have accessibility issues.  They already know what the built-in inputs are and how to deal with them.  They will rarely be able to figure out what you are trying to do when you make it all custom and snazzy.